# Not Generating IDs which start with specific value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a link that is generating IDs by looking at the last row of one of the sheets and add 1 to that. These IDs can not be some specific numbers.
For this I have two functions that is working properly and doing what I expected but now I have some new criteria. Instead of some random IDs that my generated IDs can not be, I want to tell my function that "do not generate IDs that start with 3 , 4, 8 " How can I do this?

I am not really good with vba and I may need lots of explanations.

```
Function f1(search_value As Long, rng As Range)
    For i = 1 To rng.Count
        If rng.Cells(i, 1).Value = search_value Then
            f1 = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

    f1= False
End Function

Function f2(last_ID As Long, rng As Range)
    Dim newID As Long
    newID = last_ID + 1

    While f1(newID, rng)
        newID = newID + 1
    Wend

    f2 = newID
End Function
```

Comment: Check out the LEFT function.

Comment: @SJR has the answer for your question.  In terms of what to do with that information, you will need to build logic in your `f2` function for what will happen when your last_ID+1 is one of those unwanted scenarios with an if-statement or switch.

Comment: @QuickSilver 

Hi and thanks for your answer. This is not working. It does not give me any error but simply it is not working. I mean if the last ID is 3012 then although I am writing that the IDs should not start with 3 , it generating 3013 as the next one. any idea? And on another level is it possible to tell this function to generates IDs that are not for example between 3000 and 4000 8000 and 9000? this is the same problem, I just want to know if this can work ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
Function f1(search_value As Long, rng As Range)
    For i = 1 To rng.Count
        If rng.Cells(i, 1).value = search_value Then
            f1 = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

    f1 = False
End Function

Function genID(last_ID As Long, rng As Range)
    Dim newID As Long

    If Not Left(Len(last_ID + 1), 1) = 3 Or Left(Len(last_ID + 1), 1) = 4 Or Left(Len(last_ID + 1), 1) = 8 Then
        newID = last_ID + 1
    End If

    While f1(newID, rng)
        newID = newID + 1
    Wend

    f2 = newID
End Function
```